# Spring mvc exception while validating form using annotation

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to spring mvc.I have created sample application that creates form with fields Name,age,ID.Controller method is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)

       public ModelAndView student() {
          return new ModelAndView("home", "command", new Student());
       }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addStudent(@Valid Student student,BindingResult result, Model model) {

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "home";
        }

        model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
        model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
        model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

        return "result";
    }
```

My model class Student.java

```
public class Student {
    private Integer age;
    @NotEmpty @Email
    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

It works fine when I entered correct data that is Email Id, but it gives Exception when I Enter Invalid email or NULL. Rather than Giving Error It should display appropriate error message. My view Home.jsp is

```html
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Student Information</h2>
        <form:form method="POST" action="/controller/addStudent" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
                    <form:errors path="name" >Invalid Name</form:errors>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>  
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Exception is :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at line 12

9: <form:form method="POST" action="/controller/addStudent" >
10:    <table>
11:     <tr>
12:         <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
13:         <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
14:         <form:errors path="name" >Invalid Name</form:errors>
15:     </tr>
```

root cause

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
```

Comment: you annotated name with @Email is it typo error?

Comment: for testing I given annotation @Email for name.

Comment: Please post the exception you get.

Comment: @david99world I  updated code with Exception I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate `Student student` with `@ModelAttribute`:

```
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute @Valid Student student,BindingResult result, 
       Model model)
```

**EDIT:**

Change the `new Student()` attribute name as `student` (because it will be more readable if you call a `Student` as "student"):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView student() {
          return new ModelAndView("home", "student", new Student());
    }
```

And change the `post` controller method as this:

```
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") @Valid Student student,BindingResult result, Model model)
```

Now change the `form` of your `home.jsp`:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/controller/addStudent" modelAttribute="student">
```

Comment: you have some controller method using which you are showing this page to the user.. right? can you edit your question with that method code.